# Python Regex returning Empty Strings instead of Results

Tags: python, regex, string

I have been experimenting with Python's Regex Module: Re.

I decided to write a simple expression that searches for links (`href="url"`) in a file.

Here is my Regex: `href *= *(\"|\').*\1`

When I used a site called [GSkinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), I decided to try out my expression. The results are [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?37rku), along with the code.

When I decided to try it out on python regex, I used the following code:

```
lines = """Code found in link"""
results = re.findall(r"href *= *(\"|\').*\1", lines)
print results # Ouputs: ['"', '"'] instead of two provided links
```

Why are the results outputting in empty strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findall` will only return what is captured (unless nothing is captured).  You have to capture the value you want as well:

```
r"href *= *(\"|\')(.*?)\1
```

All together you may want to use something like:

```
results = [x[1] for x in re.findall(r"href *= *(\"|\')(.*?)\1", lines)]
```